# Enable mobile broadband not working

Tags: wireless, networking, internet-connection, usb-modem, mobile-broadband

I'm using an EVDO usb Modem on 12.04. It works perfectly fine for few times. But now on wards when ever I try to connect it shows not enabled in status . I tried to enable it by ticking "Enable Mobile Broadband" but still it shows not enabled but that option gets a checked(tick) mark. And when ever I restart my system "Enable Mobile Broadband" option autamatically unchecked.  Any help please

Answer (score 0):

could be, that you are too quick or impatient ?

mobile broadband needs sometimes more time to initialize the connection.
it depends on reception of the technical devices in broadband.

my huawei mobile broadband usb stick is sometimes not working too. but it is
matter of reception (state of satellites - not state of Linux). - then it can last
5 minutes or more until it works.

Comment: @dschin1001 thanks for reply. My network name appear in list but there is status message at top where it shows signal written "not enabled"

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it is your service provider issue, It works in 2 modes, *cdma* and *evdo*, when cdma is not available, *network-manager* is unable to connect then.

If you can manage to install *gnome-ppp* (`sudo apt-get install gnome-ppp`), and then try to connect through it, it will work for you.

If you have any other wired network connection, or a friend's wifi, you can install *gnome-ppp* from there, and then try again with *gnome-ppp* using your *evdo* connection.

run `sudo gnome-ppp` after installing it, and give it ur provider dial number, username and password.

Answer (score 0):

I ran 12.04, And I also use EVDO modem device. Here is the solution:

It doesnt always work, so to know when it works,

- plug in your device
- when it shows up in neywork menu, click on "enable mobile broadband"
- when you click on that, above the network, if it says"home network(EVDO)", then you can click on the network name and use the network.
- if not unplug your device and redo all the steps until you get good results.