# cant access internet via mobile broadband

Tags: internet, usb-modem, mobile-broadband

I am new user of Ubuntu. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Almost everything is working fine, but I can't access the internet. I am connected to my mobile broadband. It is ZTE MF691 USB modem. When i connect it, it says connection established.

Comment: Please help us help you by providing more information. How are you attempting to access the internet? What happens when you try? Thank you.

Comment: post results of `ifconfig -a` and `ping -c4 8.8.8.8`

Answer (score 1):

Does it show connected in the status bar as well? Sometimes, mobile broadband shows connection established but takes a little time to start working.

Try ifconfig and ping in a command line to check if things are working fine. A little hint in this thread [Enable mobile broadband not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222982/enable-mobile-broadband-not-working?rq=1)

I hope your data package is not expired ;-)

Comment: Yeah I suppose its something to do with the data package.